# Testing two columns for one being unknown

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I identify the rows in this sample, where only **one** of the columns is "Unknown"?

- If both columns are the same, but not unknown, that's great - use either
- If one is unknown and the other column is not, that's also great - use the other.
- If they are both unknown, that's a problem easily managed

Putting a heap of nested if then type clauses doesn't sound like the smartest way to do it.

Using SQL Server 11x

```
 CASE 
        WHEN [Test1]  = 'Unknown' AND [Test2] <> 'Unknown' THEN [Test2] 
        WHEN [Test1] <> 'Unknown' AND [Test2] =  'Unknown' THEN [Test1] 
        WHEN [Test1] <> 'Unknown' AND [Test2] <> 'Unknown' AND [Test1] <> [Test2] THEN 'Issue' 

        ELSE 'xxxx'
        END AS test
```

| ROW | ID | Name | Test1 | Test2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123 | afgs | 4_Property | 2_Investigation |
| 2 | ABC193 | sdshshsh | 3_Design | Unknown |
| 3 | ABC171 | srjyjtyjtjt | 3_Design | Unknown |
| 4 | ABC147 | jtjrjrukr | 4_Property | Unknown |
| 5 | ABC100 | yeyutyurin | 3_Design | 2_Investigation |
| 6 | ABC194 | runukntykn | 3_Design | 2_Investigation |
| 7 | ABC140 | nktyunty | Unknown | 3_Design |
| 8 | ABC153 | tyukntynknk | 2_Investigation | 4_Property |
| 9 | ABC113 | kntyit | 3_Design | 3_Design |
| 10 | ABC169 | ntykntyiniil | 3_Design | 3_Design |

Comment: What do you want actually ? Please show the expected result

Comment: Please provide expect **text**  format result instead of images

Comment: I've been searching for how to put these sort of samples as table formatted text, but I just dont find it. I end up with a text editor manually spacing everything, and it takes half an hour to just create a 5 x 5 table. Is there some magic to it that I am unaware of?

Comment: Hmmm... gotta wonder what you searched for to miss [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Dale K how do I add a facepalm? My searches were "text into monospace table", "
convert text to monospace table " etc.

Comment: Relevant: [Aaron Bertrand: Bad Habits: Avoiding NULL in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/10/database-design/bad-habits-avoiding-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```sql
SELECT ROW, ID, Name,
       CASE WHEN Test1 = 'Unknown' THEN Test2 ELSE Test1 END AS Test
FROM yourTable;
```

This will report in `Test` the value of `Test1` if not unknown, otherwise the value of `Test2`.  In the case of both being unknown, it would report unknown.